# Firebase traces not showing any trace in last 24 hours?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

Firebase trace showing no network traces in last 24 hours, but I have opened my app many times.

Does Firebase only capture traces when the app is not in `debug` mode?

Answer (score 2):

Peformance Monitoring will only capture automated network traces where the plugin has been applied to the build.  If you didn't add the plugin to your build, you won't get any automated traces at all.  [Please refer to the setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android) and pay attention to step 3.

Comment: I am using android studio `3.xx`, and plugin `1.1.1` also I cannot use Firebase latest compile dependency which is `16.1.0` because my app's compile sdk is 25,  that's why I am using dependency `com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.6.0`. Also for all these dependency and plugin previously my traces were coming, how can suddenly it not work?

Comment: Did you get anything?

Comment: Hii, currently when I am checking for last `24` Hours I can see my traces, but the thing is why this data was not showing when I was trying 2 hours ago? Also when I am checking for the time of the traces they are between 5-7 PM that's why they must have included 2 hours ago too? Is this a bug or normal behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: There may have been some delays in the pipelines that process the data.  That's very possible, but I don't know if that makes it a "bug", since you'd have a hard time listing the steps to reproduce.

Comment: Happened with me again, initially, I loaded for last `24` Hrs, and it was showing no data but after an hour traces are now showing. Please fix this, maybe there is a bug.

Comment: Can you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523615/firebase-trace-showing-wrong-median-time-latency, Firebase trace time difference is really confusing?